# how to access particular file in folder through file handling in c

Tags: c, file-handling

I have suppose two text file `abc.txt` and `def.txt` in folder "my". I have a programme which directly goes to that folder and search particular file and if that particular file find out then how to access that file's information.

I know how to read write file in C through file handling but I have no idea how to search particular file and after that read that particular file to match particular string in file.

`**All these things access through file handling in C.**`

So please if any one have any solution I will be thankful for that

Example will be best way to understand .

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you know how to read a file, and  C has functions like `strstr()` that let you search for something in a string, what do you need to know to put them together?

Comment: What platform are you using? Linux? MacOS? Directory traversal and listing is unfortunately platform dependent, so it matters.

Comment: POSIX: [`#include <dirent.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/dirent.h.html)

Comment: I want to access particular file in particular folder .i have no idea how to read........you which told that will be search for particular string in file but i want to access particular folder and after that particular file and in folder their are lots of files.....If you have any code share it

Comment: @ Nikhil Linux platform

Comment: @mouviciel How to access it

Comment: If your environment is POSIX friendly, and most Linux are nowadays, `dirent.h` is already available. If you want to learn how it works, you can read the manual page, explore its _SEE ALSO_ section and ask binggle for tutorials.

Comment: @ mouviciel Any example do u have please share it

Answer (score 1):

To get a listing of the files in a directory in Linux, you can use the 'opendir', 'readdir' and 'closedir' functions from 'dirent.h'. For example:

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int ListDir(const char *pDirName)
{
    DIR *pDir;
    struct dirent *pEntry;

    pDir = opendir(pDirName);
    if (!pDir)
    {
            perror("opendir");
            return -1;
    }

    while ((pEntry = readdir(pDir)) != NULL)
    {
            printf("%s\n", pEntry->d_name);
    }

    closedir(pDir);
    return 0;
}
```